# How to compare two databases' altered tables

Tags: mysql

I have inserted new columns in one database, and I now want to add the same type of columns to a second database.  I need to know which columns are in the first database that are not in the second.  I have many tables in each database that needs column difference comparing.  I searched the web and I can only find ways to see the difference of the contents of columns in two tables.  I don't need to compare the contents, just different columns in all the tables in each database.  Each database has the same tables.

Thanks!

I found that you can do a database dump that just has the structure from phpmyadmin.

Comment: mysqldiff does what you want: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysqldiff.html - as far as a GUI goes, I know Toad for Oracle does this well and I am pretty sure Toad for MySQL has the same feature.

Comment: Dump the schema and use a comparison tool.

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940032/get-differences-between-two-tables/14941627#14941627

Comment: The script looks promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this manually? You could just use [SHOW CREATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html) to see the structure of the tables, and then something like the `diff` command in Linux to compare them.

Comment: I used ALTER commands to add columns through time. I will try the SHOW CREATE.

Comment: So, I guess I could write a script to do this.  I have over fifty tables and this would take a long time.  But this seems to be the best answer.

Comment: That's what I'd do, personally. Should be a pretty quick script - make an array of tables to compare, and loop over them. For each table, get the "show create" for each, run it through "diff", and dump that to a file or output it, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

For a commercial product answer: I use [Red Gate's SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/)  which works great. It can compare the entire schema of two databases.  It can also update your target database to match your source database.

Comment: Missed the MySQL tag. go with MySqlDif instead of my answer

Comment: We have a MySQL Compare tool at Red Gate, but it needs to be installed on Windows. http://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-comparison-bundle/

Answer (score 0):

Use **redgate SQL** compare to comapre schema of two tables.

**sql-dbdiff** works well too. Its an open source.

Comment: I don't have windows.  It is a windows application isn't it?